# Permission control using apache shiro

Tags: shiro

I am new in apache shiro, and I read almost 60% of tutorials in apache shiro page.

It is a wonderful framework, however I wonder if it can meet my requirements.

I am interested in the permission-based authentication.

For example, to make sure if the user have the permission of delete resources, we can use this:

```
currentUser.isPermitted( "resource:delete" );
```

However in our application, even a user have the permission of delete resources, he can only delete some specified resources, not all of them.

For example(just an exmaple), the resource have an filed named `createdby` to record the one who create this resource.

Now user can only delete the resources created by himself if he have the `resouce:delete` permission.

In fact, the resources which can be deleted by the user(who have authenticated and have `delete` permission) will be calculated by more constraints.

Now how to make shiro work in this suitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the extent, I have explored Shiro, I don't think it gives that level of flexibility to have a customized check. It basically functions based on roles and permission defined in the config file.

For this functionality I would suggest that you display only those records the user is allowed to delete, by have this check at query fetch level. (or) add a condition at the UI level not display the delete button if logged in user is same as created by. This is just a suggestion.

Comment: How about if the user get the delete url for one resource even he does not have the permission?

Comment: You could add delete permission check at the server side.

Comment: http://balusc.blogspot.in/2013/01/apache-shiro-is-it-ready-for-java-ee-6.html - Check if this link will be helpful, there is an example of creating jdbc realm in the config file and passing data dynamically to the query to check for permission. I haven't worked on it thou

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in Shiro but you will have to write some code. Either create a subclass of Authorizer and inject it into the security manager or create a subclass of one of the realm classes such as JdbcRealm. Then override the isPermitted method. This will need to have access to your permissions model, for example the database table or a document in a NoSQL database.

Your call to isPermitted will need to specify the resource you are deleting so you can look it up in your overridden method.

If you override the isPermitted method in the AuthorizingRealm subclass you will have access to the logged in user's principals **and** the user's Roles: this gives you quite a bit of flexibility because you can have says: user (principal) Fred with roles: Manager, Administrator. Your permissions model can then decide if Fred, a Manager or and Administrator can perform the task on the specified resource.

Hope that gives you some ideas.